# Angular2 Router throwing error when declared in normal TS class

Tags: typescript, angular2-routing

When I try to declare Router in constructor of my class, it throwing cannot resolve all parameters at run time. But if I declare it in normal (`private router: Router`) outside constructor, its not throwing any error but when I click on the link, its throwing `EXCEPTION: Cannot read property 'navigate' of undefined` at `this.router.navigate()`.

```
//Error: (SystemJS) Can't resolve all parameters for DataBindService: (?).(…)
  constructor(private router: Router) {
  }


//EXCEPTION: Cannot read property 'navigate' of undefined
private router: Router;

//full class
/// <reference path="AddedVariables.d.ts" />
import { Router }   from '@angular/router';

export class DataBindService {

  private router: Router;

  constructor(private router: Router) {
  }

  moveToAnotherPage(value: string) {
        this.router.navigate([value], { skipLocationChange: true });
  }

}
```

---

Module and service coded added.
Swap Service is provided as provides in NgModule which contains my navigate method.

```
//NgModule where Router is in provides
import {NgModule}      from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import {APP_BASE_HREF} from '@angular/common';
import { RouterModule, Router}   from '@angular/router';

import {SwapService} from "./services/SwapService";

@NgModule({
  imports: [ BrowserModule ,RouterModule.forRoot([
      { path: '', component: Swap },
      { path: 'first', component: First },
      { path: 'secound', component: Secound },
      { path: 'third', component: Third }
    ])
  ],
  declarations: [ AppComponent, Swap, First, Secound, Third],
  providers: [{provide: APP_BASE_HREF, useValue : '/' }, SwapService ],
  bootstrap: [ AppComponent ]
})

export class AppModule {

}


//the service class which have the this.router.navigate()

/// <reference path="AddedVariables.d.ts" />
import {Router} from "@angular/router";

export class SwapService {

  constructor(private router: Router) { }

  moveToAnotherPage(value: string) {
    console.log('value:%o', value);
    this.router.navigate([value], {skipLocationChange: true});
  }
}
```

Comment: You didn't load router module in NgModule, did you?

Comment: Yes, I tried that in the include section of the Ngodule, still the same issue

Comment: Please, show how exactly you use router module. This is the place where Router service becomes available to app module.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This one resolved by Making the serve as @Injectable(). The problem was I did not made my service @Injectable() and my service was a simple typescript class.

```
/// <reference path="AddedVariables.d.ts" />
import {Router} from "@angular/router";

import {Injectable} from "@angular/core";

@Injectable()
export class SwapService {

  constructor(private router: Router) { }

  moveToAnotherPage(value: string) {
    console.log('value:%o', value);
    this.router.navigate([value], {skipLocationChange: true});
  }
}
```

Comment: important line from Angular 2 site 
Don't forget the parentheses! Neglecting them leads to an error that's difficult to diagnose.

https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/tutorial/toh-pt4.html